# SQL Server 2005 Linked server Trigger insert operation giving XACT_E_TIP_CONNECT_FAILED error

Tags: sql-server-2005, hyperlink, triggers

I have 2 servers. In the first server am having a trigger that performs insert update delete transactions on the 2nd server. But whenever these triggers are called and invokes the linked server i get the error :

Msg 8509, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Import of Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) transaction failed: 0x8004d01f(XACT_E_TIP_CONNECT_FAILED).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having an invoked trigger perform actions on another (linked) server is probably going to lead to all sorts of hard to solve problems.

It would be better to use something like Service Broker to queue these actions.  Unless of course they have to be transactional.

Have you checked that MS DTC is running on both servers? What credentials is the trigger running under? Do those credentials have access on the linked server?

Comment: Yeah its got to have immediate replication for immediate use at both th servers. MSDTC is running on both the servers. and credentials are also having access to linked server. Normal insert update deletes are happening if i directly use the link server. But problem comes only when the trigger invokes that linked server.